# WP 7.5 ShareLinkTask doesn't add miniature in facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, share

My users are complaining that when they share a link to an image (directly) on facebook they don't get miniature next to it... is there something I'm doing wrong (I'm using WP 7.5 ShareLinkTask class, code below)? Or is the only way to re-implement or use other FB library?

```
        ShareLinkTask t = new ShareLinkTask();
        t.LinkUri = new Uri(model.ImageUrl);
        t.Title = model.Name;
        t.Show();
```

### -------------------------------------

**This is what I mean:**

[image: This is what I mean]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's even possible, you would need to find a 3rd party library to do it from. And I wouldn't recommend that. The image miniature is normally made by Facebook loading the shared link, and finding a picture. It's very likely that Facebook does not do this for requests through their API.

So I would suggest you ignore the request of the miniature. It's rather pointless in the end.

Comment: And since the native APIs don't expose Facebook auth tokens, using a third party framework would mean authenticating the user again.

Comment: Indeed. Alternatively having to re-direct the user through a embedded browser, and posting it by injecting JavaScript. Would be rather ugly though.

Comment: Exactly. Though I was specifically referring to not being able to share the native OSs token being the issue.

Comment: FYI, this question sparked me to create an entry on the wpdev uservoice site: [Add a GrantAccountAccessTask for obtaining temporary access to social media accounts](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/2431302-add-a-grantaccountaccesstask-for-obtaining-tempora)

Comment: Well I agree that it's pointless... but heck, you gotta make your customers happy... and using 3rd party will be messy as hell...

Comment: There is [a suggestion to create a SharePictureTask](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/2435161-sharepicturetask-or-sharephototask) on the wpdev uservoice.